Snakemake: adapt the pipeline to the new version 8.18.1 (example of combining checkpoint use inside a input function)
For a task, I need to implement the logic as in the script below. (Script source). But in the current version the flag 'directory' is only valid for outputs, not inputs.
How can this be done in the current version?
OUTDIR = "first_directory"
SNDDIR = "second_directory"
THRDIR = "third_directory"


def combine(wildcards):
    # read the first set of outputs
    ck_output = checkpoints.make_some_files.get(**wildcards).output[0]
    FIRSTS, = glob_wildcards(os.path.join(ck_output, "{sample}.txt"))
    # read the second set of outputs
    sn_output = checkpoints.make_more_files.get(**wildcards).output[0]
    SECONDS, = glob_wildcards(os.path.join(sn_output, "{smpl}.txt"))
    return expand(os.path.join(THRDIR, "{first}.{second}.tsv"), first=FIRSTS, second=SECONDS)

rule all:
    input: 
        combine

checkpoint make_some_files:
    output:
        directory(OUTDIR)
    shell:
        """
        mkdir {output};
        N=$(((RANDOM%5)+1));
        for D in $(seq $N); do
            touch {output}/$RANDOM.txt
        done
        """

checkpoint make_more_files:
    output:
        directory(SNDDIR)
    shell:
        """
        mkdir {output};
        N=$(((RANDOM%5)+1));
        for D in $(seq $N); do
            touch {output}/$RANDOM.txt
        done
        """

rule make_third_files:
    input:
        directory(OUTDIR),
        directory(SNDDIR),
    output:
        os.path.join(THRDIR, "{first}.{second}.tsv")
    shell:
        """
        touch {output}
        """

Soluton: link

You can still use the paths to the directories in input directive, just not with the special directory() flag meant to signal it is okay to delete it at the start of the run & to not detect changes to how a directory is displayed as change necessitating re-running the rules, as discussed in the documentation here.
This is the modified version that worked for me with Snakemake version 8.18.1.
OUTDIR = "first_directory"
SNDDIR = "second_directory"
THRDIR = "third_directory"


def combine(wildcards):
    # read the first set of outputs
    ck_output = checkpoints.make_some_files.get(**wildcards).output[0]
    FIRSTS, = glob_wildcards(os.path.join(ck_output, "{sample}.txt"))
    # read the second set of outputs
    sn_output = checkpoints.make_more_files.get(**wildcards).output[0]
    SECONDS, = glob_wildcards(os.path.join(sn_output, "{smpl}.txt"))
    return expand(os.path.join(THRDIR, "{first}.{second}.tsv"), first=FIRSTS, second=SECONDS)

rule all:
    input: 
        OUTDIR,
        SNDDIR,
        combine

checkpoint make_some_files:
    output:
        directory(OUTDIR)
    shell:
        """
        mkdir {output};
        N=$(((RANDOM%5)+1));
        for D in $(seq $N); do
            touch {output}/$RANDOM.txt
        done
        """

checkpoint make_more_files:
    output:
        directory(SNDDIR)
    shell:
        """
        mkdir {output};
        N=$(((RANDOM%5)+1));
        for D in $(seq $N); do
            touch {output}/$RANDOM.txt
        done
        """

rule make_third_files:
    input:
        OUTDIR,
        SNDDIR,
    output:
        os.path.join(THRDIR, "{first}.{second}.tsv")
    shell:
        """
        touch {output}
        """

The other change is that I added the initial two output directories to the input of the main rule.
You can see the set-up for working it out in a Jupyter session and result here.
You can even easily run it yourself without touching your system in a temporary Jupyter session served by MyBinder.org if you go there and follow the guide at the top to launch a session, and then upload that notebook to it and run all the cells.

Thank you very much for the detailed answer!
Perhaps you know if there is a way to use wildcards from a function for all the rules in the pipeline? I used the code from the source above with the SMP=None variable, and made modifications to the all and list_all_files rules.
I added modifications to the question, unfortunately I couldn’t post the entire code due to restrictions on the amount of code in the question.
The current version of the list_all_files rule uses the value SMP=None, how can I use the changed SMP variable instead? Really appreciate your help!

"Perhaps you know if there is a way to use wildcards from a function for all the rules in the pipeline?" I believe you are trying to get at what input functions are for? See here and here. (Or straight Python, see here or here or here.) Maybe? It's hard to tell from the ...

 snippet you added to the bottom of your original post. You could use a code sharing site or a gist to share more of the code. If that isn't possible, then it might deserve a post itself? Because I'm no seeing how that rule list_all_files would fit in to what we've been discussing.

Uploaded the code here. I can't understand, why the updated value of the SMP global variable was not saved? Instead of files: list_of_files_7537.txt,list_of_files_30172.txt... I got list_of_files_None.txt

I'd have to look more but you set SMP to None in Python and then in the default rule you set SAMPLE to SMP, which is None. So you set it. Then once you lock that in there Snakemake propagates it. Not sure what you were hoping to do there right now but I'll look later.

Thank you again for the advice and the source provided! I solved my problem. The code is available here.

Which one fixed it? The '2nd' or '3rd edition'? For helping the future you, and perhaps others, you may want to write a bit about that the solution was or put it in the notebook you link to in markdown.

I will add comments in the notebook

That's a nice example of combining checkpoint use inside a input function for when you don't know the specific files from the outset. Plus it works with very current Snakemake!

I have another question about checkpoints. I would appreciate it if you could take the time to review it. Thank you.
